# Speech Recognition - Unhandled Exception - SAPI Not Found, even when installed

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, speech-recognition, kinect, sapi

I am trying to use Microsoft Kinect, for audio recognition. This is on a Windows 7 x64 machine.

I am able to use the Kinect for Speech Recognition, using the default Windows Speech Recognition. 
I have installed Microsoft Speech SDK 5.1, SpeechPlatformRuntime (x64) and MicrosoftSpeechPlatformSDK (x64), compiling for .NET 4.0 (tried with client version too).

But when I try to do this in a wpf app in VS,

```
RecognizerInfo ri = SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers().Where(
    r => r.Id == "SR_MS_en-US_Kinect_10.0").FirstOrDefault();
var sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ri.Id);
```

It throws up the following in the Output window..

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Microsoft.Speech.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' occurred in Microsoft.Speech.dll
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' occurred in Microsoft.Speech.dll
>
> Additional information: Speech Recognition is not available on this system. SAPI and Speech Recognition engines cannot be found.

I am missing something small but important here. Since, Windows can use the Kinect to recognize the speech, I am sure all the necessary drivers are installed. Also, I have installed SAPI, and the speech SDK.

Comment: Had forgotten to install the x86 version of Microsoft Speech Platform - Server Runtime.

It's mentioned here, under "Updates for Kinect for Windows SDK Beta 2" : http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectSDKQuickstarts/Getting-Started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had forgotten to install the x86 version of Microsoft Speech Platform - Server Runtime.

It's mentioned here, under "Updates for Kinect for Windows SDK Beta 2" : http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectSDKQuickstarts/Getting-Started